# Add marker on a map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an Application in which,I get the user current location and add the marker on a Current location and it's perfectly works but i have some lat and lon and i want to show on map with Marker

Lat,Lon is in **workshopList**

**My code :**

```
public class FindServiceProviders extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    ArrayList<ServiceProviderItem> workshopList;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_service_providers);
            mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
            init();
    }


    private void  init()
    {
        setToolBar();
        workshopList = new ArrayList<ServiceProviderItem>();
        mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        fetchServiceProviders();
        mAdapter=new ServiceProviderAdapter(this,workshopList);

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }


        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
        markerOptions.anchor(.5f,.95f);
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,12f));


        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

    }

    private void fetchServiceProviders()
    {
        //volley call and populate in list
    }



}
```

Comment: @ Dhruv Tyagi then what is your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply use this method:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        for(ServiceProviderItem item : workshopList){
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(item.lat, item.lng))
            .title("Hello world"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: i got an error LatLng(double,double) in LatLng cannot be applied to (java.lang.string,java.lang.string)...
so i convert sring to double

Comment: @DhruvTyagi that is great

Comment: bt still problem is there

Comment: Please explain @DhruvTyagi

Comment: my problem is.. workshopList is populated after onMapReady function call... so in the onMapReady the workshopList shows Null

Comment: save map variable in global variable and add marker once workshopList populated.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
private ArrayList<LatLng> latlngs = new ArrayList<>(); //define arraylist of latlng
```

you can add lat long to the `Arraylist` using

```
latlngs.add(new LatLng(21.334343, 92.43434));
```

Now for showing them on Map use a for loop

```
    for (LatLng point : latlngs) {
     options.position(point);
     options.title("Marker Title");
     options.snippet("Marker Desc");
     googleMap.addMarker(options);
 }
```